# Spring-boot: Activate multiple profiles using mvn

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I'm using this command line in order to start my spring-boot service:

```
mvn clean compile -DskipTests \
    spring-boot:run \
    -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--spring.profiles.active="bo,pre"
```

I'm using two profiles : `--spring.profiles.active="bo,pre"`. As you can see from above command, I'm activating `bo` and `pre` profiles.

However, when my service starts i am seeing only `bo` profile is active:

```
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.4.RELEASE)

2019-12-30 09:33:08.013  INFO...  : Starting ApiApplication on psgd with PID 30578 (/home/jeusdi/projects/repositori-digital/rep-digital-api/target/classes started by jeusdi in /home/jeusdi/projects/repositori-digital/rep-digital-api)
2019-12-30 09:33:08.022 DEBUG ...  : Running with Spring Boot v2.0.4.RELEASE, Spring v5.0.8.RELEASE
2019-12-30 09:33:08.027  INFO ...  : The following profiles are active: bo
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this property in the command line instead: `-Dspring-boot.run.profiles="bo,pre"`

```
mvn clean compile -DskipTests spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles="bo,pre"
```

Comment: This is due to the mvn spring-boot plugin... It accepts `-Dspring-boot.run.profiles="bo,pre"` to start the application with many profiles. Why it only takes one profile your way, might be a bug, I am not sure.
If you try : java -Dspring.profiles.active="bo,pre" -jar YourFatJar.jar, then you will have all your profiles active. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-adding-active-profiles) you have to add `spring.profiles.include` as below.

```
spring.profiles.include:
  - pre
```

Both profiles should be activated when you used below properties in `application.properties` file

```
spring.profiles.active=pre
spring.profiles.include=bo
```

Or If you really want to specify active profiles as command line arguments you can use below command for multiple profiles.

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--spring.profiles.active=bo,--spring.profiles.include=pre
```

And if you want to add more active profiles use below command.

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--spring.profiles.active=bo,--spring.profiles.include=pre,--spring.profiles.include=another
```

Answer (score 0):

mvn clean compile -DskipTests spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=foo,boo